# Use Sed/Awk to extract first three unique instances of the line

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I have a list with 20000 probes, is there a way to extract the first three lines/occurences for each probe using sed/awk?

```
Example of dataset:
    Probe1 A  GTTAGAGGAGGTGGAAGAGC
    Probe1 B  CTGAGGTCGGGACGGAGCAC
    Probe1 C  GATGTAGGCGGTTGGCGTGG
    Probe1 D  GTTGGCGAAGTCACATCTAG
    Probe1 E  CATGTCGCCGACTCCGTCGA
    Probe1 F  GTGATGTTCTGAGTACATAG

    Probe3 A  GATTGTAGGTTTCCTGCCAG
    Probe3 L  ACCCAGCCAGGGGAAAACCA
    Probe3 Z  GGAGATGTAGGCGGTTGGCG
    Probe3 Y  GGAGATGTAGGCCTTAAAAA
    Probe3 D  GATTGTAGGGGTCCTGCCAG
```

Desired output:

```
Probe1 A  GTTAGAGGAGGTGGAAGAGC
Probe1 B  CTGAGGTCGGGACGGAGCAC
Probe1 C  GATGTAGGCGGTTGGCGTGG
Probe3 A  GATTGTAGGTTTCCTGCCAG
Probe3 L  ACCCAGCCAGGGGAAAACCA
Probe3 Z  GGAGATGTAGGCGGTTGGCG
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '++a[$1]<4' file
```

to remove the empty lines

```
$ awk '++a[$1]<4 && NF' file
```

Comment: So simple and elegant. Thank you. Just one thing: can you please explain ++a part?

Comment: Nice. The `++a[$1]` increases the value associated with unique values in the first field. The line is printed when less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use sed or awk here (if you'd like to use Python). Unless I've mistaken your question, this should do it:

```
probes = [
"""Probe1 A  GTTAGAGGAGGTGGAAGAGC
Probe1 B  CTGAGGTCGGGACGGAGCAC
Probe1 C  GATGTAGGCGGTTGGCGTGG
Probe1 D  GTTGGCGAAGTCACATCTAG
Probe1 E  CATGTCGCCGACTCCGTCGA
Probe1 F  GTGATGTTCTGAGTACATAG""",
"""Probe3 A  GATTGTAGGTTTCCTGCCAG
Probe3 L  ACCCAGCCAGGGGAAAACCA
Probe3 Z  GGAGATGTAGGCGGTTGGCG
Probe3 Y  GGAGATGTAGGCCTTAAAAA
Probe3 D  GATTGTAGGGGTCCTGCCAG"""]

for probe in probes:
    for i, line in enumerate(probe.split("\n")):
        print(line)
        if i >= 2:
            break
```